# Autoware.ai Documentation

Tags: ros, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
Do you know where is the Autoware.ai documentation?
I am trying to find information about different launch files, but I can’t find the previous doc.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/366357/autoware.ai-documentation/) by [Mohsen.ciw](https://answers.ros.org/users/49848/mohsen.ciw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-11-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

All currently-available documentation for Autoware.AI can be found at https://github.com/Autoware-AI/autoware.ai/wiki.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Whitley](https://answers.ros.org/users/4390/josh-whitley/) with karma: 1766 on 2020-12-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1